# Проблема с классом на php вывод данных

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Суть проблемы переделал плагин favorites для своего сайта структура немного отличалась [вот оригинал плагина](https://github.com/UniPixen/Niradrien/blob/master/applications/collections/modeles/favorites.class.php)

отличия структуры базы 
product и members в оригинале
у меня items и users

Все это работает за исключением двух вещей не выводятся категории и пользователь автор товара за место него выводится пользователь текущей сессии.

**Подскажите где у меня ошибка**

структуру таблицы я сделал такую

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `favorites`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favorites` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `favorites`
--
INSERT INTO `favorites` (`user_id`, `item_id`, `datetime`) VALUES
(1, 2, '2015-11-25 19:54:04'),
(1, 3, '2015-11-25 19:54:15');
```

Переделанный класс

```
    class favorites extends base {
    public $usersWhere = '';

    public function getAll($start = 0, $limit = 0, $where = '', $order = "`datetime` DESC") {
        global $mysql;

        $limitQuery = '';

        if ($limit != 0) {
            $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start, $limit ";
        }

        if ($where != '') {
            $where = " WHERE " . $where;
        }

        $mysql->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM `favorites`
        $where
        ORDER BY $order
        $limitQuery
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $return = array();
        $this->usersWhere = '';

        while ($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
            $return[] = $d;

            if ($this->usersWhere != '') {
                $this->usersWhere .= ' OR ';
            }

            $this->usersWhere .= " `user_id` = '" . intval($d['user_id']) . "' ";
        }

        $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();
        return $return;
    }


    public function get($itemID) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM `favorites`
        WHERE `item_id` = '" . intval($itemID) . "'
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return $mysql->fetch_array();
    }

    public function isInFavorites($itemID, $userID) {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM `favorites`
        WHERE `item_id` = " . intval($itemID) . " AND `user_id` = " . intval($userID) . "
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getItems($userID, $start = 0, $limit = 0, $where = '', $order = '`fav`.`datetime` DESC') {
        global $mysql;

        $mysql->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM `favorites`
        WHERE `user_id` = " . intval($userID) . "
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $whereQuery = '';

        while ($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
            if ($whereQuery != '') {
                $whereQuery .= ' OR ';
            }

            $whereQuery .= " `fav`.`user_id` = " . intval($d['user_id']);
        }

        $limitQuery = '';

        if ($limit != 0) {
            $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start, $limit ";
        }

        $mysql->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM `items`
        LEFT JOIN `favorites` as fav ON `fav`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
        WHERE ($whereQuery) $where
        ORDER BY $order
        $limitQuery
        ");

        if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->usersWhere = '';
        $return = array();

        while ($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
            $categories = explode('|', $d['categories']);
            unset($d['categories']);
            $d['categories'] = array();
            $row = 0;

            foreach($categories AS $cat) {
                $categories1 = explode(',', $cat);
                foreach($categories1 as $c) {
                    $c = trim($c);

                    if ($c != '') {
                        $d['categories'][$row][$c] = $c;
                    }
                }

                $row++;
            }

            $return[$d['id']] = $d;

            if ($this->usersWhere != '') {
                $this->usersWhere .= ' OR ';
            }

            $this->usersWhere .= " `user_id` = '" . intval($d['user_id']) . "' ";
        }

        $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();
        return $return;
    }

    public function add($itemID, $userID) {
        global $mysql;

        if ($this->isInFavorites($itemID, $userID)) {
            return false;
        }

        $mysql->query("
        INSERT INTO `favorites` (
        `user_id`,
        `item_id`,
        `datetime`
        )

        VALUES (
        '" . intval($userID) . "',
        '" . intval($itemID) . "',
        NOW()
        )
        ");

        return true;
    }

    public function delete($itemID, $userID) {
        global $mysql;

        if (!$this->isInFavorites($itemID, $userID)) {
            return false;
        }

        $mysql->query("
        DELETE FROM `favorites`
        WHERE `user_id` = '" . intval($userID) . "' && `item_id` = '" . intval($itemID) . "'
        ");

        return true;
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
_setView(__FILE__);
_setTitle($langArray['favorites']);

require_once ROOT_PATH . '/market/apps/favorites/models/favorites.class.php';
$favoritesClass = new favorites();

$limit = 10;
$start = (PAGE - 1) * $limit;
$order = '';

if (!isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $_GET['sort'] = '';
}

switch($_GET['sort']) {
    default:
    $order = '`fav`.`datetime`';
    $sort = $langArray['date'];
    break;
}
abr('sort', $sort);

if (!isset($_GET['order']) || $_GET['order'] == '' || $_GET['order'] == 'desc') {
    $_GET['order'] = 'desc';
    $order .= ' DESC';
}

else {
    $_GET['order'] = 'asc';
    $order .= ' ASC';
}

$items = $favoritesClass->getItems($_SESSION['user']['user_id'], $start, $limit, " AND status = 'active' ", $order);
if (is_array($items)) {
    require_once ROOT_PATH . '/market/apps/users/models/users.class.php';
    $usersClass = new users();

    $users = $usersClass->getAll(0, 0, $favoritesClass->usersWhere);
    abr('users', $users);
}
abr('items', $items);

require_once ROOT_PATH . '/market/apps/categories/models/categories.class.php';
$categoriesClass = new categories();

$categories = $categoriesClass->getAll();
abr('categories', $categories);

abr('paging', paging('/favorites/?p=', '&sort=' . $_GET['sort'] . '&order=' . $_GET['order'], PAGE, $limit, $favoritesClass->foundRows));
```

html

```
        {if $items}
    <div class="row">
        {foreach from=$items item=p}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div href="/{$languageURL}items/{$p.id}/{$p.name|url}" onclick="location.href ='/{$languageURL}items/{$p.id}/{$p.name|url}'" class="hover">
                <div class="bottom-grup">
                    <a class="material-icons md-20" href="">&#xE87D;</a>
                    <a class="material-icons" href="">&#xE03B;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="{$data_server}uploads/items/{$p.id}/{$p.thumbnail}" alt="{$p.name|escape}" class="thumbnail">
            </div>
            <div class="meta">
                <div class="price">
                    {$currency.symbol}{$p.price|string_format:"%.0f"}
                </div>
                <div class="name text-truncate">
                    <a href="/{$languageURL}items/{$p.id}/{$p.name|url}">{$p.name}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="user text-truncate">
                    От <a class="pop" data-href="/users/ajax-user-info/{$users[$p.user_id].username}" href="/user/{$users[$p.user_id].username}">{$users[$p.user_id].username}</a>
                    В {foreach from=$p.categories item=e}
                    {foreach from=$e item=c name=foo}
                    <a href="/categories/{$categories[$c].id}/{$categories[$c].name|url}.html">{$categories[$c].name}</a>
                    {if !$smarty.foreach.foo.last} &#xf105; {/if}
                    {/foreach}
                    {/foreach}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/foreach}
    </div>
    {/if}
```

Возможно проблема где то здесь

```
public function getItems($userID, $start = 0, $limit = 0, $where = '', $order = '`fav`.`datetime` DESC') {
            global $mysql;

            $mysql->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM `favorites`
            WHERE `user_id` = '".intval($userID)."'
            ");

            if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            $whereQuery = '';

            while ($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
                if ($whereQuery != '') {
                    $whereQuery .= ' OR ';
                }

            $whereQuery .= " `fav`.`user_id` = '".intval($d['user_id'])."' ";

            }

            $limitQuery = '';

            if ($limit != 0) {
                $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start, $limit ";
            }

            $mysql->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM `items`
            LEFT JOIN `favorites` AS fav ON `fav`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`   
            WHERE ($whereQuery) $where
            ORDER BY $order
            $limitQuery
            ");

            if ($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            $this->usersWhere = '';
            $return = array();

            while ($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
                $categories = explode('|', $d['categories']);
                unset($d['categories']);
                $d['categories'] = array();
                $row = 0;

                foreach($categories AS $cat) {
                    $categories1 = explode(',', $cat);
                    foreach($categories1 as $c) {
                        $c = trim($c);

                        if ($c != '') {
                            $d['categories'][$row][$c] = $c;
                        }
                    }

                    $row++;
                }

                $return[$d['id']] = $d;

                if ($this->usersWhere != '') {
                    $this->usersWhere .= ' OR ';
                }

                $this->usersWhere .= " `user_id` = '".intval($d['user_id'])."' ";
            }

            $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();
            return $return;
        }
```